# Thread.Abort doesn't seem to throw a ThreadAbortException because of AcceptSocket

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-abort, threadabortexception

I am calling `ChannelServer.ListeningThread.Abort` on the following thread, however nothing seems to happen. I would like to be more specific, but I can't think of anything more. There seems to be no `ThreadAbortException` that is thrown, and this exception should be thrown regardless of the blocking listener (it works perfectly on threads that are blockingly-receiving).

**Important EDIT**: With a `ManualResetEvent.WaitOne` instead of `AcceptSocket`, as Lyrik has suggested for testing, it works perfectly. How come `AcceptSocket` blocks the `ThreadAbortException`?

**LINK**: This forum thread seems to discuss the same issue, although I cannot figure anything out of it: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=319436&page=413

```
ChannelServer.ListeningThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
{
    Log.Inform("Waiting for clients on thread {0}.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ChannelClientHandler.Initialize)).Start(ChannelServer.Listener.AcceptSocket());
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {
            Log.Inform("Aborted client listening thread {0}.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            break;
        }
    }
}));
ChannelServer.ListeningThread.Start();
```

Comment: I can't imagine that this is the right way to go about whatever it is you're trying to do. You really shouldn't be spawning this many threads.

Comment: @Adam, that's a normal piece of code on a server... starts a new thread for each accepted connection.

Comment: Ouch, that's not normal on anything but a trivial server. Thread per connection will generally cause problems when scaling up.

Comment: It is a trivial server, and it is not the point of the question. :)

Comment: same behavior if you change the try to just do the AcceptSocket?

Comment: @James: Just tested, same behavior.

Comment: if you do the .Abort() call and then a client comes in (so AcceptSocket stops blocking), does it THEN throw?

Comment: BTW, since the behavior here seems to be that the call is blocking the kernel (and the Abort on the managed thread isn't enough to get it to unblock), as per the MSDN page you may want to loop on Pending instead:

"If you want to avoid blocking, use the Pending  method to determine if connection requests are available in the incoming connection queue."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, but it's incredibly sloppy and thread-wasting. Could anyone just point me to a way to throw an exception that "AcceptSocket" won't automatically catch?

```
ChannelServer.ListeningThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
{
    Log.Inform("Waiting for clients on thread {0}.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            ChannelServer.ClientConnected.Reset();
            ChannelServer.Listener.BeginAcceptSocket(new AsyncCallback(ChannelClientHandler.EndAcceptSocket), ChannelServer.Listener);
            ChannelServer.ClientConnected.WaitOne();
        }
        catch (ThreadInterruptedException)
        {
            Log.Inform("Interrupted client listening thread {0}.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            break;
        }
    }
}));
ChannelServer.ListeningThread.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting that error, but here is a simple example that works:

```
ManualResetEvent mrse = new ManualResetEvent(false);
Thread test = new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                mrse.WaitOne();
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No problem here...");
            }
        }
    });

test.IsBackground = true;
test.Start();

Thread.Sleep(1000);
test.Abort();
Console.ReadKey();
```

So it works for me... I assumed you've stepped through the debugger and your break point inside the catch statement wasn't hit, is that correct?

Note: it's bad practice to call `Abort`, instead you should call `Interrupt` and handle the `ThreadInterruptedException`... it's much safer.

Comment: "So it works for me... I assumed you've stepped through the debugger and your break point inside the catch statement wasn't hit, is that correct?"

Correct.

Comment: @Lazo, where do you make the abort call?

Comment: @Lirik: From another thread, which uses this method: ''ChannelServer.ListeningThread.Abort();''

Does the fact that it comes from another thread hinder the process? If so, I guess I'll use delegates.

Comment: @Lazlo, in my example it comes from another thread (the main thread), so that's definitely not the problem. Is the code you posted the **simplest** example with which you're seeing the problem? There is no other code that might be causing issues?

Comment: I am absolutely sure this is the most direct call - I can have breakpoints and log information before and after the abort call, I am absolutely SURE the abortion gets called. I have used extremely similar code for receival procedures and it works. I'm really puzzled...

Comment: @Lirik: Note: I just tested with Interrupt, still doesn't work. Thanks for the tip, though. :)

Comment: I suspect Accept is catching thread-related exceptions and performing its own bookkeeping.

Comment: @Yuliy: Seems to be so, although Receive on a Socket doesn't, so I smell unusual inconsistency in the framework. Maybe I'll have to do it with the built-in async. methods (BeginAccept/EndAccept).

Comment: as per the MSDN page, it seems simpler to just change your while loop to put the existing body inside a if (Pending) (potentially with an else that does a sleep(0) or sleep(1) or sleep(500) or something).  Then you can change the 'true' to 'canceled == false' (canceled being some instance or static bool you add) then the other thread can just canceled = true instead of having to Abort() :)

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple `AcceptSocket2` extension method (sorry for the lack of imagination regarding the name...).
It works exactly as the original `AcceptSocket` method.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

/// <summary>
/// Extensions to TcpListener
/// </summary>
public static class TcpListenerExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Accepts a pending connection request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tcpListener">The TCP listener.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="T:System.Net.Sockets.Socket" /> used to send and receive data.
    /// </returns>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.InvalidOperationException">The listener has not been started with a call to <see cref="M:System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start" />.</exception>
    /// <PermissionSet><IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.EnvironmentPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Unrestricted="true" /><IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Unrestricted="true" /><IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Flags="UnmanagedCode, ControlEvidence" /><IPermission class="System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterPermission, System, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Unrestricted="true" /></PermissionSet>
    public static Socket AcceptSocket2(this TcpListener tcpListener)
    {
        Socket socket = null;
        var clientConnected = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        clientConnected.Reset();
        tcpListener.BeginAcceptSocket(delegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            try
            {
                socket = tcpListener.EndAcceptSocket(asyncResult);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            { }
            clientConnected.Set();
        }, null);
        clientConnected.WaitOne();
        return socket;
    }
}
```